# What can be done with Bootstrap to prevent the website contents from shifting way right at wider browser widths?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am attempting to use bootstrap to build a very simple webpage.

I can get everything to look right on regular width browsers, but when I go full screen on a wide screen monitor in Chrome all the text and buttons jumble up to the right.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to avoid this problem.  Is there a solution or is bootstrap just not able to work with widescreens?  (I am 100% OK with there being blank space on the left and right, I am just trying to avoid everything shifting way to the right after I stretch the browser to a wider width.)

```
<div class="container mark">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-11">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Company Name</h1>
        <p class="lead">Company Description</p>
        <a href="mailto:email" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn More - Email us</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>          
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you offsetting it on large screens if you don't want it to? ie. take out col-lg-offset-11

Comment: If I remove both col-lg-offsets it does eliminate the problem.  But I am attempting to give space between the left margin of the container by using a col-lg-offset-1, after your advice I dropped the offset but it still has an issue.  Now it jumbles to the left as it gets wider.  Likely the issue is that I need to use a different class to offset the text in the container slightly to the right.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap classes do not need to be nested as you have them. You seem to want something that takes up 11 of 12 of the Bootstrap grid columns, offset by one column on large devices only - this can and should be specified on the same `div`. Try something like:

```
<div class="container mark">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Company Name</h1>
        <p class="lead">Company Description</p>
        <a href="mailto:email" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn More - Email us</a>
    </div>          
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/herifa/1/)

There are examples in the [Bootstrap Grid Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Thanks.  Ultimately I removed the offset and just went with .col-xs-12 to go full width on all screen sizes and didn't pad the side.